# Get me off the JavaScript postback Failboat

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've got to call two js functions, setfocus on textbox and stop a postback from occuring on single buttonclick.  I think I got it if I could only intercept the postback.  My js skills are on par with weaksauce.

**test case**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="JsTextFocus.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.JsTextFocus" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
        function aMethod() {
            var dowork = 'bleh';
        }
              function setFocusOnTextBox() {
                  TextBox1.Focus();
              return false;//Stop the postback..FAIL
          }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imageBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/document_Small.gif" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="aMethod();return setFocusOnTextBox();return false;" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page load shouldn't fire after OnClientClick**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("PS happened at " + DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referring to TextBox1 in yout setFoucs.. function which is unknown at that point.  Use document.getElementByID to get a reference to textbox and then call **focus** not **Focus**.

```
function setFocusOnTextBox() 
{         
  var TextBox1 = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
    TextBox1.focus();              
    return false;         
}
```

You can remove the return false at the end of the Image ClientClick handler.
i.e.:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imageBtn" 
runat="server" 
ImageUrl="images/document_Small.gif" 
CausesValidation="false" 
OnClientClick="aMethod();return setFocusOnTextBox();" />
```

Comment: That works, can you elaborate a bit on why the TextBox1 is unknown at this point?

Comment: It is because when you say TextBox1, the js context tries to see if there is any variable/reference by that name. To access the TextBox1 element you have to either get it by id using document.getElementById or use the document.forms reference to access the forms child elements i.e. document.forms[0].TextBox1